# Shorthand for no re-assignment with the nil coalescing operator (??)

Tags: swift

Is there a shorthand for doing this:

```
var x: Int = 42;
var y: Int? = nil
x = y ?? x
```

E.g. re-assigning same value/not re-assigning, if y is nil

Edit: To clarify, in the example, I'd like to keep the value (42) of x, if y is nil. A better wording might be an "*assign if not nil*" operator.

Edit2: As @rintaro pointed out, reassignment may incur side-effects which I would like to avoid. I could resort to `if let` like this:

```
var x: Int = 42;
var y: Int? = nil
if let y = y {
    x = y
}
```

but that is pretty verbose.

Comment: I don't understand what you want :-?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no builtin operator for that.

Use `map` instead:

```
map(y) { x = $0 }
// OR
y.map { x = $0 }
```

Note: this technique is useful when the variable is observed:

```
var x: Int = 42 {
    didSet {
        println("didSet")
    }
}

var y: Int? = nil
x = y ?? x // `didSet` is called
map(y) { x = $0 } // `didSet` is not called
```

Comment: Exactly. My version has side effects, which I want to avoid with out resorting to `if let` or similar.